# To Do, Or Do Without

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme

I saw this rhyme the other day and couldn't make sense of it. Perhaps I am missing something. Can you help?

> Oh, Rick and Corry battle mice.
>   Two step out, in steps Man.
>   A trap, a nail, and bell are back.
>   'E can con. Oh, 'e can!

Hint:

> Arable way. Jam.

Comment: This smells Shakespearean...

Comment: Should _'E_ and _'e_ be understood as __HE__ and __he__ respectively?

Comment: @Alconja By the rood, thou takest not my meaning.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Sure, if you like.

Comment: Rick and Corry reminds me of Pawn Stars. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A post to open:

> Each word in this ode can have **door** attached to make another word.  (Sometimes homophones are used and these are italicized below.)

Oh, Rick and Corry battle mice.

> *Odour*, *Doric* <sup>and</sup> *corridor* [battledoor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/battledoor) *dormice*.

Two step out, in steps Man.

> *Tudor* doorstep outdoor, indoor doorsteps doorman.

A trap, a nail, and bell are back.

> *Adore* trapdoor, *adore* doornail, <sup>and</sup> doorbell *ardour* backdoor.

'E can con. Oh, 'e can!

> *Doe(r)* *candour* condor. *Odour*, *doe(r)* *candour*!

Hint:  Arable way. Jam.

> *Adorable* (include do or sound of *door*) doorway. [*Doorjamb*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doorjamb)

The Title and closing remarks

> To **Do**(,)**or** **Do** Without is adorned with Door.
>
>  Without much further ado I am uncertain of 'and' also 'E where it may attach 'Do' or may be for soundalike 'doer'. Also Hugh posted a cryptic comment 'By the rood (backdoor), thou takest not my meaning.' in response to a question on Shakespearean similarity, so this is full of doors.

Comment: Congrats! I was thinking adorned for and (yes, a bit of a stretch but it sounded good to me) and dory (‘e) is a kind of fish. The title was meant to suggest that the puzzle “does without” the keyword. Well done!

Comment: Ah. And as you pointed out I cheated a little on the hint: I was doubling the r in a-dor-rable. The more usual spelling of the word in the first line is battledore. Not super common but not an obscure dictionary addendum either. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your lines it is like

First line means

> Rick and Corry looking for the solution for mice in their room/house

Second line means

> The mouse is getting in and out.They are unable to catch the mouse.

The third line means

> They are saying that they need a mouse trap, nails(to block the other exit/entrance of mouse), and bell (which rand on mouse caught)

Fourth line means

> They are saying we can capture the mouse

Comment: Please hide your spoilers