# Compound word cousins

Tags: word, seasonal

Find a single word answer with the property that [compound words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compound_word) formed from the answer have a word in common with compound words formed from each of the following :

[image: Selection]

Text version:

> ```
> BERRY  BOTTLE  CRYSTAL   CUSHION   FLY      HIGH  
> HIKE   INDEX   KETTLE    MARKET    MUSTARD  PLAYER  
> POT    RED     RING      ROCKET    SALAD    SNOW    
> SWEET  TIME    TROPICAL  VACUUM    VOICE    WINE
> ```

For example: the words FAMILY, RADISH, SKI are connected in this way by CHESTNUT:

family tree - chestnut tree, horseradish - horse chestnut, waterski - water chestnut.

---

Updates and clarifications upgraded:

1. The answer is associated with the two types of compound words used: **open** and **closed**.
2. There is a different link word for each of the 24 grid words.
3. The  grid shape was cracked by M Oehm in a [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57613/compound-word-cousins#comment177591_57710):

   > The 6x4 grid looks a bit like an advent calendar.
4. Inspiration: [To Do, Or Do Without](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57265/to-do-or-do-without/57322#57322) by Hugh Meyers.

Comment: Just to make sure that I'm understanding the question right: Say the one word answer is A, then for each B on the list, there exists some other word C such that both C-B (or B-C) and C-A (or A-C) are valid compound words?

Comment: @DqwertyC - exactly and neatly defined! There is a shortcut to hitting upon the answer to this question - then finding the connecting words.  (The title is just generic.)

Comment: I have proposed an edit to include the *$\LaTeX$ (latex) version* of the $6\times 4$ word grid :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **window**.

The associated compound words could be:

> **bay**berry   —   **bay** window
>      **glass** bottle   —   window**glass**
>   crystal **lattice**   —   **lattice** window
>      **seat** cushion   —   window **seat**
>         fly**screen**   —   window**screen**
>         high **time**   —   **time** window
>          **tax** hike   —   window **tax**
>        index **case**   —   window **case**
>   **electric** kettle   —   **electric** window
>   **transfer** market   —   **transfer** window
>    **french** mustard   —   **french** window
>    player-**manager**   —   window **manager**
>      pot **marigold**   —   **marigold** window
>          **rose**-red   —   **rose** window
>           **key**ring   —   Windows **key**
>     rocket **launch**   —   **launch** window
>    salad **dressing**   —   window **dressing**
>        snow**mobile**   —   Windows **Mobile**
>        sweet **shop**   —   **shop** window
>        time **frame**   —   window **frame**
>    tropical **storm**   —   **storm** window
>    vacuum **cleaner**   —   window **cleaner**
>         voice **box**   —   window **box**
>         wine**maker**   —   window**maker**
>
>  Some of these work better than others, but a few, especially cleaner and dressing, fit remarkably well. I'm sure I haven't got all the intended answers and some are a bit of a stretch. Googling "window" yiedls a lot of stuff related to our favourite OS and consequently I've taken the liberty to include references. (I find Windows key acceptable, but Windows Mobile a bit of a stretch. Perhaps a windows mobile might be something hanging in the window of a nursery. Funny how many things you can combine with French and with bay.)
>
>  Possible links I didn't use: sash, front, shopping, light, pane, sill, picture.

Finally, the hints:

> *The answer is associated with the two types of compound words used: open and closed.* — Like compound words, windows may also be open and closed.
>
>  *The 6x4 grid looks a bit like an advent calendar.* — A classical advent calendar has 24 small windows.
>
>  *Inspiration: To Do, Or Do Without by Hugh Meyers.* — That puzzle was about doors, which are related to windows in that they are openings in walls.
>
>  (My first thought was that the answer could be door here, too. There were some promising pairs, for example door / bottle opener and keyring / door key. But when I learned about the window tax and saw the window cleaner and widow dressing solutions, I changed my mind to window.)

Comment: Wonderful! I had only two differences (8. Therapeutic 24. Bar) and the first of these isn't as good as yours. Happy didn't fall for the trap door.

Comment: One more on my side, blind which I had for 18 (again yours is popular). No need to update your answer.

Comment: Congratulations! @Tom I'm honored. I noticed this because I got an upvote on the referenced puzzle but arrived too late to contribute. I guess you could say I came in through the back door.

Comment: @HughMeyers - I'm in awe of your posts. I don't have your poetic abilities! This was easy to make but hard to solve.

Comment: Last ones, for pot I had plant and for ring curtain. (Apols for all comments I may tidy up.)

Answer (score 6):

I'll take a guess at this. The answer could be:

> **Christmas**
>  This fits the category "seasonal", although I haven't been able to find all combinations yet...

Some of the combos might be:

> **cracker**berry
>  bottle **tree**
>  crystal **ball**
>  cushion **flower??**
>  fly **box**
>  high **time** (as hinted by OP)
>  hike ??
>  index **card**
>  kettle**bell**
>  market **day**
>  white **mustard**
>  **card**player
>  **flower**pot
>  red **light**
>  **seal** ring
>  rocket ??
>  **green** salad
>  snow**berry**
>  sweet **pickle**
>  **Father** time
>  tropical **disease**
>  vacuum ??
>  voice **box**
>  **rose** wine

Some possible link words that I haven't used yet:

> block, present, eve, carol, beetle, ham, creep, cake, fern, cookie, club, stocking, list, season, cactus, happy, merry, cheer, pudding, star, tide, factor

Thanks M Oehm for noting the grid is shaped like:

> **an advent calendar**

Comment: I had the same thought, but couldn't find too many links that really worked. I also tried to use every link just once, which made everything more difficult. For what it's worth, I had market day and mustard tree. And I think the 6x4 grid looks a bit like an advent calendar.

Comment: Thanks! I also tried using every link just once at first, but filled out the doubles anyway. I'll add a list of link words I haven't used yet. Maybe we can figure out the rest.

Comment: Correct grid interpretation (thanks M Oehm)! Great selections above but there is another word which is fitting for the grid cells. This word is also associated (in action) to the two compound hyponym types used.

Comment: On the High time today in the hint. I thought it was Dec 6 today (I've now wound my watch on) so the High was supposed to clue that position in the grid - although I might get away with saying it's high time can mean past the time. Unintentionally High is linked directly with the answer via a 20th Century detective novel. Apologies for this misdirection as I know this puzz involves so many options.

Answer (score 2):

Well a partial answer here:

> The required word is BLUE

As, the possible compound words from the grid are

> Berry     - Black Berry
>  Kettle    - Electric Kettle
>  Tropical  - Tropical Sea
>  Rocket    - Sky Rocket
>  Hike      - Mountain Hike
>  Sweet     - Sweet Lime
>  Time      - Time Eternal
>  Red       - Blood Red

And all the added words on the RHS of the above list can combine with

> Blue to form meaningful compound-words such as
>  Black and blue,
>  Electric blue,
>  Sea blue,
>  Sky blue,
>  Mountain blue,
>  Lime blue
>  Eternal Blue
>  Blue Blood

Comment: Right idea (no connecting 'and' is used) and looking for a different word which compounds with all examples. The compound words are present in Wiktionary (except for one pair which is in Wikipedia main heading).

Answer (score 2):

Could the word be:

> GARDEN

The possible word combinations that I could find are these:

1.

> *TEA* | **BERRY** 
>  *TEA*  | **GARDEN** 
>  [Teaberry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teaberry)  =>  [Tea Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tea_garden)

2.

> **BOTTLE** | PARTY 
>  **GARDEN** | PARTY 
>  [Bottle Party](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bottle_party) => [Garden Party](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garden_party)

3.

> ROCK | **CRYSTAL** 
>  ROCK | **GARDEN** 
>  [Rock Crystal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rock_crystal) => [Rock Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rock_garden)

4.

> LARGE or SQUARE | **CUSHION** | BEADS or LESS or LINER or LINERS or WALL 
>  LARGE or SQUARE | **GARDEN** | BEADS or LESS or LINER or LINERS or WALL 
>  Large Cushion => Large Garden 
>  Square Cushion => Square Garden 
>  Cushion Beads => Garden Beads 
>  [Cushionless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cushionless) => [Gardenless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenless) 
>  Cushion Liner(s) => Garden Liner(s)

5.

> HOUSE or FLOWER | **FLY** | SPRAY or SHEET 
>  HOUSE or FLOWER | **GARDEN** | SPRAY or SHEET 
>  [Housefly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/housefly) => House Garden 
>  [Flowerfly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flowerfly) => [Flower Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flower_garden) 
>  [Fly Spray](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fly_spray) => Garden Spray 
>  Fly Sheet => Garden Sheet

6.

> **HIGH** | CENTRE(S) or MAINTENANCE or STREET 
>  **GARDEN** | CENTRE(S) or MAINTENANCE or STREET 
>  [High Centre(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high_centre) => [Garden Centre(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garden_centre) 
>  [High Maintenance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high-maintenance) => Garden Maintenance 
>  [High Street](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high_street) => Garden Street

7.

> SUMMER or ROADSIDE | **HIKE** 
>  SUMMER or ROADSIDE | **GARDEN** 
>  Summer Hike => Summer Garden 
>  Roadside Hike => Roadside Garden

8.

> BOTANIC | **INDEX** 
>  BOTANIC | **GARDEN** 
>  Botanic Index => [Botanic Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/botanic_garden)

9.

> TEA | **KETTLE** | LAKE or LAKES 
>  TEA | **GARDEN** | LAKE or LAKES 
>  [Tea Kettle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tea_kettle) => [Tea Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tea_garden) 
>  [Kettle Lake(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kettle_lake) => Garden Lake(s)

10.

> VERTICAL | **MARKET** | BASKET 
>  VERTICAL | **GARDEN** | BASKET 
>  [Vertical Market](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertical_market) => [Veritcal Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertical_garden) 
>  [Market Basket](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/market_basket) => Garden Basket

11.

> **MUSTARD**  LESS or LIKE or SEEDS 
>  **MUSTARD**  LESS or LIKE oe SEEDS 
>  [Mustardless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mustardless) => [Gardenless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenless) 
>  [Mustardlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mustardlike) => [Gardenlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenlike) 
>  Mustard Seeds => Garden Seeds

12.

> SECRET | **PLAYER** 
>  SECRET | **GARDEN** 
>  Secret Player => Secret Garden

13.

> FRAGRANT or STACKED or TEA or VEGETABLE | **POT** | PLANT or PLANTS 
>  FRAGRANT or STACKED or TEA or VEGETABLE | **GARDEN** | PLANT or PLANTS 
>  Fragrant Pot => Fragrant Garden 
>  Stacked Pot => Stacked Garden 
>  [Teapot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teapot) => [Tea Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tea_garden) 
>  Vegetable Pot => [Vegetable Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vegetable_garden)

14.

> **RED** | FLOWERS or LIGHT(S) 
>  **GARDEN** | FLOWERS or LIGHT(S) 
>  Red Flowers => Garden Flowers 
>  [Red Light(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/red_light) => Garden Light(s)

15.

> FRONT | **RING** | ROAD(S) 
>  FRONT | **GARDEN** | ROAD(S) 
>  [Front Ring](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/front_ring) => [Front Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/front_garden) 
>  [Ring Road(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ring_road) => Garden Road(s)

16.

> **ROCKET** | LIKE 
>  **GARDEN** | LIKE 
>  [Rocketlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rocketlike) => [Gardenlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenlike)

17.

> **SALAD** | LESS or LIKE 
>  **GARDEN** | LESS or LIKE 
>  [Saladless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saladless) => [Gardenless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenless) 
>  [Saladlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saladlike) => [Gardenlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenlike)

18.

> **SNOW** | PEA(S) 
>  **GARDEN** | PEA(S) 
>  [Snow Pea(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snow_pea) => [Garden Pea(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garden_pea)

19.

> **SWEET** | PEA(S) 
>  **GARDEN** | PEA(S) 
>  [Sweet Pea(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sweet_pea) => [Garden Pea(s)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garden_pea)

20.

> TEA | **TIME** 
>  TEA | **GARDEN**  
>  
>  [Teatime](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teatime) => [Tea Garden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tea_garden)

21.

> **TROPICAL** | HOUSE 
>  **GARDEN** | HOUSE 
>  [Tropical House](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tropical_house) => [Garden House](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garden_house)

22.

> NON | **VACUUM** | ER or LIKE 
>  NON | **GARDEN** | ER or LIKE 
>  [Nonvacuum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonvacuum) => [Nongarden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nongarden) 
>  [Vacuumer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vacuumer) => [Gardener](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardener) 
>  [Vacuumlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vacuumlike) => [Gardenlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenlike)

23.

> WONDERFUL | **VOICE** | FUL 
>  WONDERFUL | **GARDEN** | FUL 
>  Wonderful Voice => Wonderful Garden 
>  [Voiceful](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voiceful) => [Gardenful](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenful)

24.

> NON | **WINE** | LIKE 
>  NON | **GARDEN** | LIKE 
>  [Nonwine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonwine) => [Nongarden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nongarden) 
>  [Winelike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/winelike) => [Gardenlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gardenlike)

Open or closed words have been separated by *|*.

You could replace the related words (highlighted in bold) with **ANSWER** to get it's compound words.

*Note: Sorry for the bad markup formatting. Still learning!*

Comment: Great work, but looking for recognised compound words, for e.g. 1. blue/answer doesn't seem one.

Comment: @Tom: I have also updated the answers, and added links to wiktionary site wherever applicable. Wanted to check with you if my "ANSWER" is the correct one, else will think about alternate answer.

Comment: Shadow - many great fits here, though there is another answer which doesn't use: less, like, non. For a direct way to the word look at what elements of the grid, as identified in [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57613/compound-word-cousins#comment177591_57710),  may be called.

Comment: By the way, write “$\$$\implies$\$$” to generate $\implies$ or “$\$$\Rightarrow$\$$” to generate $\Rightarrow$. Otherwise, $(+1)$ :)