# Bird is NOT the word!

Tags: word, cipher, visual, rebus, english

I can't get into my computer.
It's password protected, you see, and I got hit by a cement truck this morning in front of the Compound Word Store.
Luckily, I have this nifty cheat sheet. It was conceived for just such an occasion, but as my head is still quite scrambled, I need help deciphering it.

---

> In each of the word pictures below is the word "word." Now picture one *single, unique word* that can replace all of the "word" words so that the new word, when combined with the picture depicted by the "word" picture, will make a new, commonplace phrase, concept or—you guessed it!—word.
>   Next, use these numbers to get the password: {4,5,6,3,4,5}
>   The password and new word will be related.

### 1.[image]

### 2.[image]

### 3.[image]

### 4.[image]

### 5.[image]

### 6.[image]

Hint:

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that @Bass has the right idea with

> FOOT being the key word.

The six words might be

> footloo**S**e (Kick off your Sunday shoes!) 
>  foot crea**M** 
>  squar**E** foot 
>  footba**L**l 
>  foothil**L**s 
>  puss**Y**foot

Which means that the final answer is

> **SMELLY**, by putting together the nth letter of the non-root word (Thanks, @Chowzen!)

Comment: 4,5,6 are right, but you should be looking at the new part only, not the common half of the compound word

Comment: @Chowzen The 1st one I'm still pretty sure is wrong, but the other two sound more reasonable, as does the final answer now...thanks for the update/hint as well! :)

Comment: Maybe rot13(*nagfl srrg*)?

Comment: Yes, I thought that might've been a hard one. Think of Kenny Loggins and dancing Kevin Bacon. I'll mark this as accepted in a while.

Comment: That's actually really clever, Kenny Loggins did it for me! I think I've cleaned up my answer fully now. Great puzzle!

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid this puzzle is right up there with [Compound word cousins](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57613/compound-word-cousins): there is too much "give" in the link between the intended solutions and the clues. This lack of rigidity makes the solving process tedious and unrewarding: basically anything can be made to fit, usually almost up to the point of reading out the password, at which phase you get .. something. It may be the correct answer, or it may not, but there's no way to predict that, and since there's no way of knowing if you are even close, you'll have to try tweaking the answers a bit, and so on, and so forth, I think you get the point.

All this means that the only way to solve this puzzle is to chase wild geese for hours, discarding all the nice ideas you spent all that time working on, and you'll just have to hope that at some point you happen to stumble upon something that actually works. (If you want to see what such process looks like, just check the non-accepted answers to the [other puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57613/compound-word-cousins). There's so much good effort wasted there..)

As quick examples to support my point, I offer the following (presumably wrong) answers:

> House music
>  House dressing (well, it's an unmarked tube, so it might be salad dressing)
>  3D printed house
>  Roundhouse
>  House in the countryside
>  Housecat

or just as likely,

> [clubfoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clubfoot)
>  [tube foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_feet)
>  cubic foot
>  football
>  foothills
>  pussyfoot (or even, [cat's-foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antennaria_dioica))

Comment: Yes, I had come to this understanding and was here to upload a new (hopefully more pointed) clue/hint when I saw your comment/answer. (BTW, you've stepped right into it, but three of the answers need adjusting.)

Answer (score 2):

Is the word,

> Copy

Well,

> I only have one for 2 and 6 to be Copy+Paste and CopyCat.

Comment: Well, I certainly appreciate the effort! Good form, nice stance, but you only hit 33% of your target. Care to reload and take another shot? :)

Comment: The amount of times I've seen the word "word" has made it lose meaning to me... is the thinking right to say something like 4 being rot13(nebhaq gur jbeyq)?

Comment: That looks promising! Thanks @iiiidk